# How do I pass a type to a function called in the inner constructor ("this" equivalent)?

Tags: function, julia, this

I have a function that runs inside different structs, how to know in which struct that my function runs in.
Example:

```
function foo()
#here I need to find out the name of the struct  this function runs (which constructor called it) 
   in, A or B
end



  struct A
    arg
    function A(arg)
        foo(arg)
      return new(arg)
     end
   end



 struct B
    arg
   function B(arg)
        foo(arg)
      return new(arg)
    end
 end
```

Comment: How do you want to know? A print statement? Does `foo` do something different depending on which struct it's in?

Comment: No I just need the name of the struct, because I need to save some values from that function depending on the name of the struct, for example: outputValueFrom_A=10

Comment: Well that's impossible without passing the struct instance into the method; you straight up do not give the method any information about the struct. Alternatively you could just make two separate functions to do different things `fooA() = :A` and `fooB() = :B`.

Comment: ahh okay thanx:), I'm wondering if there is any implementation like “this” keyword in julia.

Comment: Not exactly, but `new` kinda lets you do something like that. Think about it, `this` in other languages is intended to let you access the instance or class a method belongs to. That's not a thing in Julia, you have to pass an instance into a method. So why not use the instance created by the bare constructor `new`? It's not like you have to return it immediately. I'll post an example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the instance created by `new` in your inner constructor to dispatch `foo`. Of course, you are free to customize `foo` to do much more varying things than just print the symbol of the type.

```
foo(t::T) where T = Symbol(T)

struct A
  function A()
    instance = new()
    println("foo was called in ", foo(instance))
    return instance
  end
end

struct B
  function B()
    instance = new()
    println("foo was called in ", foo(instance))
    return instance
  end
end

A() # prints: foo was called in A
B() # prints: foo was called in B
```

Answer (score 3):

If it is in runtime you normally would use multiple dispatch in one way or another or pass the argument or pass the type (see other answers and comments).

However, if it is for debugging you could use `stacktrace()`:

```
function foo()
   st = stacktrace()[2]
   println("Debug info :", st)
end
```

And now using your structs:

```
julia> A();
Debug info :A() at REPL[3]:3

julia> B();
Debug info :B() at REPL[12]:3
```

#EDIT if you plan to pass type an elegant high-performance solution could be:

```
function foo(::Type{A})
    @show "typeA"
end

function foo(::Type{B})
    @show "typeB"
end

struct B
    function B()
        foo(B)
        return new()
    end
end
```

And now:

```
julia> B();
"typeB" = "typeB"
```

Comment: Thank you! If I passed an argument (I have edited the question), could it work? Because I'm passing argument anyway. I'm just trying to avoid passing the instance

Comment: I added an edit showing the nice way with avoiding passing the instance

Comment: @ahm ahm Not in general. For example, A(1) and B(1) would both call foo(1), which has to do the same thing for both. The closest thing to `this` is really using the instance A() or its type A as an argument. My one suggestion to this post is `foo(::Type{T}) where T = @show Symbol(T)` to make a general one-liner.

Comment: @BatWannaBe I understand he does not want to pass the instance so I gave code edit with type. Passing the instance is shown in your code so he has all cases :)

Comment: Indeed, and your version dispatches just as elegantly. In fact, it is more flexible because you can get the type from an instance but not the other way around. So my version can't do `foo(A)`, but your version can do `foo(A)` and `foo(typeof( A() ))`.